# How do I stop my MySQL query generating two rows for one reference?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query which gets all the bookings for an agent, and all the rooms for a booking and performs some simply calculations:

```
Select a.code, a.name, a.areacode, a.agentgroup, 
  Sum(br.basicprice) As TotalRevenueYTD, 
  Sum(b.adults + b.children + b.infants) As Pax,
  Count(br.bookingref) As Bookings
From booking_record br 
  Inner Join agent a On br.agentref = a.code
  Inner Join bookingroom b On b.bookingref = br.bookingref
Where br.bookingdate > '2011-01-01' And br.bookingdate < Date(Now())
Group By br.agentref
```

The tables are set out so as a booking_record has 1 agent (agentref -> a.code). An agent may have many bookings, and a booking may have many rooms. In this particular case my revenue and bookings are coming out incorrect because if a single booking has more than 1 room, the row is returned more than once (and as such, the basicprice is counted twice, the booking is counted twice etc).

Any ideas how I can return the correct information?

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: **Immediate issue** - you have a problem in  your logic.  MySQL allows `GROUP`ing by unaggregated fields which leads to random data.  you are grouping by a field that's **NOT EVEN IN YOUR SELECT LIST** which is a major red flag.

Comment: @JNK, `br.agentref = a.code`, so the OP is really grouping by `a.code`, which IS in the select list.

Comment: Can you add the table definitions to the question including what the PK is in each table?

Comment: @Johan - and he's also selecting several other fields which are not aggregated OR grouped

Comment: @JNK, `a.name, a.areacode, a.agentgroup` are fully dependent on the key `a.code`, so they don't need to be grouped by, all the others are aggregated fields.

Comment: @Johan - you are making a lot of assumptions here, which is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @JNK, I base the `assumptions` on the description of the OP. My point is that **IF** you're grouping on the primary key, **THEN** the subfields that a fully dependent on that key do not need to be grouped or aggregated. Which is the reason why MySQL does not require all field to be grouped. As far as I can tell the OP has kept this rule in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys - the SQL isn't actually written by me, it's generated by a reporting tool ;) However, I shall take a look into these and post table info if Johan's answer doesnt fix my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
SELECT a.code, a.name, a.areacode, a.agentgroup
       , Sum(br.basicprice) As TotalRevenueYTD
       , sum(b1.pax) As Pax
       , Count(br.bookingref) As Bookings
FROM booking_record br 
INNER JOIN agent a On br.agentref = a.code 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b.bookingref, Sum(b.adults + b.children + b.infants) as pax 
  FROM bookingroom b 
  GROUP BY b.bookingref) AS b1 ON b1.bookingref = br.bookingref
WHERE br.bookingdate >= '2011-01-01' 
  AND br.bookingdate <= Date(Now())
GROUP BY a.code
```

Note that as @JNK points out, this code is based on the assumption that a.code is a unique or primary key of table `agent`. If it is it will work correct.
If is is not it will yield indeterminite results.